# Want bullets in error message via json call in mvc c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
messages = String.Join("<br></br>" + Environment.NewLine, ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors).Select(v => v.ErrorMessage + "" + v.Exception));
```

I want bullets in error message and i did above code please help me.
my code in mvc c#.
where to apply

Comment: I apllied <li></li> but not worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use

> `<li></li>`

accordingly and style using CSS.